# Model prediction in data generator Keras

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing

I'm working on a Keras model with images separated into patches. 

I have a quite peculiar pipeline:

```
for i in range(n_iteration):
        print("Epoch:", i, "/", n_iteration)
        start = time.time()
        self.train_batch, self.validation_batch = self.get_batch()
        end = time.time()
        print("Time for loading: ",end - start)
        K.set_value(self.batch_source, self.train_batch[0][:self.batch_size])
        K.set_value(self.batch_target, self.train_batch[0][self.batch_size:])

        pred = self.model.predict(self.train_batch[0])

        K.set_value(self.gamma, self.compute_gamma(pred))

        hist = self.model.train_on_batch(self.train_batch[0], self.train_batch[1])
```

I need to compute based on the prediction of my model at a time *t* (for a given batch) a certain value named gamma.This value is then taken into account in my loss function but is not differentiable, therefore I canno't integrate it's computation in my loss function. 


When measuring the necessary time for loading and training, it appears that the bottleneck is in the loading phase.

 My question is: Is it possible to load several batches (the function self.get_batch() while computing the prediction, gamma and training on an other batch?


I guess the idea would be to create some kind of queue in which I store my batches, but I don't really know how to do that.


PS: in my get_batch function I'm accessing an hdf5 file, can it cause any trouble in multiprocessing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you look at fit_generator ? It supports using multiple workers in order to parallelise the reading of data. It means that the data generator is called by this class: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L531. Even with a single worker (default) it runs the generator in parallel with the execution of the computational graph.

Comment: Indeed I have, however the trouble is that I want to keep track on my batches. Before each training step I need to compute the prediction on my batch. I don't think I can integrate that inside the batch generator, am I wrong ?

Comment: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Write a custom generator to return the gamma as well along with the Y. Write a custom loss function which uses both the gamma and Y to calculate the loss.

Comment: I second @ManojMohan recommendation: use a generator and custom loss function. Even because with a custom loss you don't have to compute the prediction again. The loss function will be passed the value of the prediction.

Comment: But the computation of my gamma is sadly undifferentiable (I forgot to clarify that point, sorry)